# Use Boost to force convert path to Linux format

Tags: c++, linux, file, boost

I am trying to use Boost to take an input path string (which could either be in Windows \\ format or Linux / format) and ALWAYS return the Linux format because a later regex call depends on its input being in Linux format.

I tried using make_preferred() but unfortunately this function converts to Windows format when being run on Windows, which is not what I want. Is there some function call I don't know about that allows you to define which format you want to convert to and just send it as a parameter?

EDIT: To elaborate, the input path that comes in is correct for the platform it's being run on. I need to use boost to force convert this to use forward slashes rather than backslashes. Also, I need to do so without #ifdef WINDOWS statements.

Comment: What's the Linux equivalent of `C:`?

Comment: Andrew Henle has a very good point.  Linux paths all mount from a common root whereas windows paths do not.

Comment: Please read my edit. I need to convert all backslashes to forward slashes on a string using boost, and without having to use an #ifdef statement.